# Draw polygon interactively in Python Dash and get zonal histogram/statistics

Tags: polygon, zonal-statistics, plotly, dashboard

**The problem**

I would like to be able to *interactively draw a polygon* on a choropleth map, where I can draw as many vertices as needed. After drawing the polygon, I would like to get back the zonal histogram or zonal statistics from the choropleth map within the polygon.

**What I read**

I checked out this link: https://community.plotly.com/t/draw-polygon-in-mapbox-with-dash-python/34917/5, which shows how to solve my problem, but only the polygon drawing and on Leaflet, and not how to get back the zonal statistics or histogram (see the answer from Emil also with an example picture)

**The question**

1. Can I solve described problem somehow in Plotly instead of Leaflet?
2. If not, how can I return the zonal histogram or statistics that I draw on a map?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use a program like qgis which has these capabilities built in?

Comment: Hi @Llaves, yes the aim is to provide the results to people who do not have any qgis experience. They aim is that they can boot up the dashboard and just play around, and don't need to install qgis and learn it.

Comment: @Thierry did you ever find out how to do this?

Comment: Hi @kms, unfortunately I did not. I am currently trying out the capabilities of Earth Engine together with the geemap python package that might offer this.